# Attendance System Calculate Total Time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, math, logic

I am currently working on an attendance system for my robotics team using mySQL and PHP using CodeIgniter as a framework. I have functionality for signing in and signing out but the first 2 times the user signs in, it displays their total time by subtracting the length of the current session from 24 hours. It's hard to explain. The output is like this for the first few times the user signs out:

X has signed out

Time: 00 hours 0 minutes 8 seconds
Total Time: 23:59:52

It subtracts 8 seconds from 24 hours for some reason for the first 2 times the user signs out.

Here's the code (It's very messy and I apologize, this is my first big project in php)

```
    public function clock_in($pin_number)
    {
        // Used to get user id
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('pin_number' => $pin_number));
        $id = $query->row_array()['user_id'];

        // Used to get Id of Active event
        $query2 = $this->db->get_where('events', array('is_active' => 1));
        $event_id = $query2->row_array()['event_id'];

        // Used to get last clock of user
        $query3 = $this->db->get_where('clocks', array('user_id' => $id));
        $clock_array = $query3->result_array();
        $size = count($clock_array);
        if($size == 0)
        {
            $data = array(
                'user_id' => $id,
                'event_id' => $event_id,
                'time_stamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'clock_in' => TRUE
            );
            $this->db->insert('clocks', $data);
            echo $this->get_name($pin_number);
            echo " Has signed in for the first time <br>";
            echo "Welcome to the Team!";
            return;
        }
        $result = $clock_array[$size-1];
        $data = array(
            'user_id' => $id,
            'event_id' => $event_id,
            'time_stamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'clock_in' => $this->is_clock_in($id)
        );
        // Has the user previously clocked in?
        if(!$this->is_clock_in($id))
        {
        //If yes, store the time the user clocked
        $time = new DateTime($result['time_stamp']);
        //Store the current time
        $current = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $difference = $current->diff($time);

        $time_a = strtotime($result['time_stamp']);
        $time_b = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        echo $this->get_name($pin_number);
        //echo $difference->format('%i')/60;
        echo " has signed out<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        if(abs($time_b-$time_a)/60/60 > 16)
        {
            echo "You forgot to sign out<br>";
            echo "You will not be credited<br>";
            echo "You have been automatically signed in";
            $data['clock_in'] = TRUE;
            $this->db->insert('clocks', $data);
            return;
        }
        echo "Time: ";
        //Display how long the user has been signed in
        echo $current->diff($time)->format('%H hours %i minutes %s seconds');
        $totalTime = new DateTime("0-0-0 0:0:0");
        if($size == 0)
        {
            $totalTime->add($current->diff($time));
        }
        for($i = 1; $i < $size; ++$i)
        {
            $row = $clock_array[$i];
            $row2 = $clock_array[$i - 1];
            if($row['clock_in'] == FALSE)
            {   
                $time_stamp = new DateTime($row['time_stamp']);
                echo $time_stamp;

                $last_time = new DateTime($row2['time_stamp']);
                echo $last_time;

                $delta;
                if($size == 0)
                {
                    $delta = $last_time->add($time_stamp);
                }
                else
                {
                    $delta = $last_time->diff($time_stamp);
                }

                echo $delta;
                $totalTime->add($delta);
            }
        }    
        $totalTime->add($current->diff($time));
        echo "<br>Total Time: ";
        echo $totalTime->format('H:i:s');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So you are explaining your task and showing your code, but what is your actual question?

Comment: Oh sorry, I want to find out why it's subtracting the current session time from 24 hours. It only does it for the first two times that the user signs out, after that, it displays the correct total time. When the user signs in for the first time for 5 seconds, it says they have a total time of 23:59:55 which is obviously not true. they only have a total time of 5 seconds.

Comment: I just want to know why it's giving this output and how to fix it.

Comment: ok. In your first line, you have `$current` and `$time`, but you are not providing how these are defined. Can you provide that?

Comment: Ok I added some more code to clear things up a bit. It's not the prettiest code though. I swear not all my code looks this bad.

Comment: why are you using this line to check if the user has logged in `!$this->is_clock_in($id)` if you are already checking that the user has  a "clock" row `$size = count($clock_array); if ($size == 0) {` ? if there are no "clocks" doesnt it mean the user has not clocked in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81812/discussion-between-assorted-nuggets-and-codegodie).